# Variables do not take their assigned value (that's at least, what gdb tells)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm stepping through the following code snippet:

```
(71)   int nonzero = this->matrix->getNonzero();
(72)   int rows = this->matrix->getRows();
```

You would expect that `nonzero` and `rows` take the return value of the respective function. But no - in gdb, they have the value 200 before line 71 and 72, and they both have the value 200 after it. Altough the two functions return values different from 200.

On the other hand, the variables seem to take the right value. When printing them with cout, they have the expected value. Only gdb seems to give a wrong value.

You can see this in the debugging session protocol:

```
0:  71      int nonzero = this->matrix->getNonzero();
0:  (gdb) 0:  (gdb) print nonzero
0:  $1 = 200
0:  (gdb) print this->matrix->getNonzero()
0:  $2 = 102437
0:  (gdb) n
0:  72      int rows = this->matrix->getRows();
0:  (gdb) print nonzero
0:  $3 = 200
0:  (gdb) print this->matrix->getRows() 
0:  $4 = 19044
0:  (gdb) n
0:  74      this->tmp.init("tmpCUDA", rows, 1, rows, true);
0:  (gdb) print rows
0:  $5 = 200
```

Seems that I'm either doing a really stupid mistake or ran into something really strange. I have to say that these lines worked well in previous versions and cause trouble after a major change in the structure of the program, but not that class.

(And yes, I did `make clean` and reboot. Code is not optimized. The getter functions are all const and can not change the member variable.)

Comment: is this optimized code? Debugging infos might not correspond to source lines if some optimization happened

Comment: don't print the function (I guess you getting the address) print the member from the class or the condition.

Comment: @SHR: No, I get the right result from the function as well as from the member itself.

Comment: is the `getNonzero` is const? (`int getNonzero() const`) maybe it changes the member value... (like use `=` instead of `==`)

Comment: It's const and does not change the member.

Comment: It's possible that the compiler is optimising despite you not requesting any optimisations, or that the compiler is emitting incorrect or incomplete debug info, leading gdb to look in the wrong location to determine the variable's value. Do you have a specific small program that shows the behaviour you're now getting, and a specific compiler brand, version and set of flags that should be used to compile that program?

Comment: Try outputting the variables (e.g. with `printf`) to confirm this

Comment: What compile flags are you using. Try passing `-O0` if you are using `gcc`

Comment: In the meanwhile, it turns out, that the problem occurs when a string literal as an argument to a function (but not for a stream) is present in the same function...